# Webview - empty space in right after loading html

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

There is an empty space in a right side of the page after loaded it in a webview, so I zoom it out on the screen ("physically") and everything fits OK. Adding zoomOut() in code doesn't help. How to programmatically make a complete zoom out to fit html on the screen? 
[image]
1) Firstly it's loaded, but zoomed in, so there is an empty space in the right side (like on the second screenshot)
2) After zooming out on the screen - everything fits OK. How to always get fully zoomed out screen?

```
view.webview.visible(false)
        view.webview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                view.webview.visible()
                //view.webview.zoomOut() I've tried this, but with no success
            }
        })

        view.webview.loadUrl("My html page")

        view.webview.settings.let { settings ->
            settings.builtInZoomControls = true
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            settings.displayZoomControls = false
            settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        }
        view.webview.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
```

I've searched similar topics on stackoverflow, but with no result.

My html page (without inner content):

```
<html>
<style>
p.dline {
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

body {
    padding-left: 16px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-right: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #747474;
}

</style>
<meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,text/html,charset=utf-8' >
<body>
......
```

Comment: You are most probably having troubles with the styling in the html of your page, making it more then 100% of your screen. Make sure it's responsive.

Comment: Galya, I've added html code in the topic. I removed all of my styles in html, but webview shows it same like earlier

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have any inline styles on the html elements especially width attributes